# Typecast any OleDbReader Double/Int16/Int32/Int64 to C# double?

Tags: c#, ms-access, casting, type-conversion, oledb

If I create a new OleDbReader as follows:

```
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(query, ActiveConnection);
reader = command.ExecuteReader();
while(reader.Read())
{
   someList.Add((double)reader["columnHeader"]);
}
```

How can I ensure that I'm always returned a double from the column specified, if the data returned is typed as Int16/Int32/Int64 instead of Double? Do I have to create a handler for each possible type? I know `Double.Parse` exists but it only accepts strings. So, while I could use `ToString()` beforehand I feel that this is probably not the most straightforward way to typecast.

Similarly, for another column, I wish to ensure that any String/Double/Int16/Int32/Int64 values return as strings. Will `ToString()` handle these cases?

I'm fine with potential overflow errors, as I'll check for exceptions regardless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should call `Convert.ToDouble()`, which has a handler for each type.

By contrast, `ToString()` will work for any non-null value.  (as long as it overrides `ToString()`; all numeric types do)

Comment: Perfect. Not sure how I didn't come across that before.